# VueJs: How to use array in double braces {{}}?

Tags: arrays, vue.js

How to use array in vue js

```js
var myObject = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {message: ["Hello"],["Word"]}
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <h1>{{ message[0] }}</h1>
</div>
```

I want to show "Hello" in H1 tag, anyidea, thank you very much

Comment: You have a syntax error in your message array and if you'd checked your console, you would see the error message. You want `message: ["Hello", "World"]`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Firstly, make sure that you initialise the data property properly.

```
data: {
 message: ["Hello", "Word"]
}
```

Then you can do `message[0]` if you know exactly that `"Hello"` is at the `index` of `0`.

You can also have an array of objects like so

```
data: {
  message: [{
  first: "Hello",
  second: "Word"
 }]
}
```

then to access it you would write `{{message[0].first}}`

You can even write functions inside the `{{}}` like `{{message.find(el => el == "Hello World")}}`

I hope it helps.

Comment: You might be right even though I cannot see "syntax error" as one of the reasons to flag the question. At the same time, I do not wish to discourage new users from asking questions and learning by downvoting if I feel that the question itself is not spam or somehow abusive.

Comment: I didn't say anything about downvoting. There's a specific close vote for typographical / syntax errors

Comment: It seems that I do not have that option yet. Other than to downvote or flag. I suppose more reputation is required for that.

Comment: Exactly. https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges You are on the way to get there. Good luck.